# Why does the variable give me only the last digit when using the function which is supposed to convert decimal to binary?

Tags: python, loops, binary

Why when calling the function it gives me only the last binary digit?

```
def deci_bi():
    decimal = int(input("Enter decimal number: "))
    binary = ''
    while True:
        result = decimal // 2
        remainder = decimal % 2
        decimal = result
        binary = str(remainder) + binary
        if result == 0:
            break
        return binary

print(deci_bi())
```

Comment: Consider *when* you intend the `return` statement to be executed. *In* the loop or *after* the loop?